# Failed - Server Problem while Downloading File from URL in PHP

Tags: php, html, file, download, force-download

This has been really annoying me. When I try to download a file, it says Failed - Server problem.
But Its actually working well, when I declare the file path directly

```
 $file = "wp-content/Devis_10.pdf";
```

But However I am trying to change the file path depending on the user sales id, is this case it shows download error.

```
$part2 = $current_user->sales_id; 
$part1 = "wp-content/Devis_";
$part3 = ".pdf";
```

What am I missing here ??

This is my complete code

```
<?php 
    
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $email = $current_user->user_email;
    $part2 = $current_user->sales_id;
    
    $part1 = "wp-content/Devis_";
    $part3 = ".pdf";
    
    
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    $file = $part1.$part2.$part3;   //Result example "wp-content/Devis_10.pdf";
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Devis.pdf"');  
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
    flush(); 
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        echo fread($fp, 65536);
        flush(); 
    }
    fclose($fp);
    
    
    ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/devis.php" download="Devis.pdf">
         <button type="button">Download</button>
         </a>
```

Comment: Use `readfile($file);` instead of that loop [The Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: And if you echo the generated path before download ( or instead of ) is it as expected?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hello, I used it too. its still not working.  the problem seems to be somewhere in $file path declaration

Comment: In my experience a full path rather than a relative path works best for reading files as you are doing here.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, Hello! a full path seems to be working well. but this document is a unique file for each user. so it has to be different depending on who's logged in.

Comment: You should only have 1 `Content-Type` header, not 3.

Comment: @user3783243 sorry, I literally wrote the code here.. but yeah usually I declared them as variables.

Comment: Do you have multiple `Content-Type`s in real code? It would be best if you copied real code then trimmed down/filtered here.

Comment: @user3783243,  I edited it and what is see now is the real code